# Rendering Content Multiple Times in a Node

Tags: theming, entities

I'm starting to dig deeper into themeing and I'm thinking maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Basically I want to break apart the way the content is laid out in my `node--example.tlp.php` file.

I've started doing that with some simple render statements like  `print render($content['group_factory_images']);`

I started running into trouble when I wanted to pull the label off of the normally rendered flow and place them somewhere else with something like `print render($content['group_factory_images']['label');`

This wasn't working so I started to try and pull other items in, to see if it was a syntax issue or something else.

I came away with 2 questions: What is the right syntax to get labels rendered in a node?

And then; Can you only render a piece on content once? For example could I do something like rendering the body twice in the same node? (not that I would want to, but it illustrates the point I think:

```
print render($content['body']);

// other items rendered

print render($content['body']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display of a label is handled by the Field and not the template. The HTML for the field is passed to the template layer from the field API and the label HTML is lumped in with the field information itself. So basically you cannot alter or move the printing of the label in the template layer of theming. Consider the field data and the field label as one item in templating (i.e. `$content['field_name']` contains the field data and label as one. Altering the label display (display label or not, inline, etc.) is done in the field display settings for the content type. The only way to alter the label is to do so at the field display level and again it is passed to the template with the field data as a final product.

Rendering content more than once, yes it can be done.

Comment: So I cannot hide the flield label in the content type "Manage Display" settings and then do something in the `tpl` file to show that label where I want to?

Comment: @ErikHanson You are correct.

Comment: I never would have guessed that, I've always assumed you could pull almost anything forward. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah it's a pain. I recently ran into this trying to add a "help" icon next to the a field title on the add-to-cart form with Drupal Commerce. I had to give up till the new DC came out where I could write hooks to tear apart the add-to-cart form. There was no way of modifying it because it came as a field object.